# estimating the tail of $p$-series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, asymptotics, divergent-series

Let $  p >0 $ be a positive real. We consider the $p$-series

$$ \sum_{ n > N} \frac{1}{n^p} $$

where $ N \to \infty.$

An application of the integral test show that in the case where the series converges (namely for $ p > 1,$ then one has the estimate

$$ \sum_{ n > N} \frac{1}{n^p} \ll N^{1-p},$$

as $ N \to \infty.$

My question is the following.

> Question 1: Under what assumptions one can obtain the tighter upper bound
>   $$ \sum_{ n > N} \frac{1}{n^p} \ll N^{-p},$$
>
> as $ N \to \infty?$

edit: After the comments of Sandeep Silwal , I have decided to change a bit the range of summation, hoping to get something better than $ \ll N^{1-p}.$ Here is the new question:

> Question 2: Let $ \delta \in (0,1).$ Under what assumptions on p, is it true that
>
> $$ \sum_{ n > N^\delta} \frac{1}{n^p} \ll N^{-p\delta} \quad ? $$

Finally, I think (if such an estimate is valid) that one could sum at the level $ n \geq h(N)$ where $h (N)$ is a positive slowly, increasing to infinity function, with $h(N) = o(N), \quad N \to \infty.$

Comment: Its not really possible because just $N^{-p} + \cdots (2N)^{-p}$ already give you $N^{1-p}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula might also be useful.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: Thank's for the comment. I had the impression that with a refined of (summation by parts ?) one can obtain such an estimate. The point is that I cannot really remember what I have seen. Also, what can we conclude in the range $ 0 < p < 1 ?$

Comment: Well in that range the sum diverges but if you take a finite sum, then even in that case, the integral approximation is going to be very good. Check out the euler maclaurin formula I posted above, it gives you the error in the approximation between a sum an the corresponding integral. For functions of the form x^p, the formula is very accurate if i remember correctly

Comment: @SandeepSilwal: Yes, you are right. Do you think that if we consider a "tail" of the shape $$ \sum_{ n > h(N) } \frac{1}{n^p} ,$$ with $h(N) $increasing to infinity slower than $N$ we can hope for some else?

Comment: I am not sure..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An integral comparison shows that $$(N+1)^{1-p} \leq (p-1)\sum_{n \geq N}{n^{-p}} \leq N^{1-p}.$$

Thus $$\sum_{n \geq N^{\delta}}{n^{-p}} \sim \frac{N^{-\delta(p-1)}}{p-1} >> N^{-\delta p}.$$

Comment: Thank's for the reply. Because, I am a bit confused, one question. This works only for $ p >1,$ right ? What about the case $ 0 < p \leq 1 ?$

Comment: For $0 < p \leq 1$ the series doesn’t converge so the remainer is always infinite.

Comment: Thank's the comment. Yes, you are absolutely right. My comment makes no sense. On the other hand, looking more carefully at your reply, what you prove is the the tail is asymptotic equal to $N^{- \delta(p-1)}.$ So, trivially we have that a rough upper bound would be $ N^{-\delta}.$

Comment: That’s assuming $p \geq 2$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I should have mentioned it but I forgot it. I was playing around with the values of $p.$ Thank's for the remark.